# Вывод строк в лайтбокс

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Здравствуйте!
На wordpress'е есть портфолио, которое выводит записи и при нажатии показывает картинку в лайтбоксе. Как вывести характеристики товара в лайтбоксе? Я не могу добавить код php в js файл лайтбокса. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Javascript может получить данные, которые хранятся в базе, только с помощью php. Соответственно, если у вас подготовлена нужная для js информация, то вы можете ее использовать в коде javascript.

Comment: Нет код php в js файл вы добавить не можете, но можете вывести необходимую вам информацию в шаблоне страницы, а уже затем этими данными манипулировать из JS. Либо же отправлять из js запрос к серверу и полученный ответ обрабатывать как необходимо.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно данные, полученные через РНР в шаблоне WordPress, "локализуют" при помощи функции `wp_localize_script`, а уже потом из javascript работают с ними и передают в лайтбоксы.

Comment: За что минус? Можно аргументировать?

Comment: Судя по тому, что автор хочет писать php код в js файлах, на счет минусов можно не париться.

Comment: А так, да. Немного поясню:
Данная функция добавляет дополнительные данные перед указанным скриптом, который должен быть в очереди на вывод. По сути с помощью нее перед выводом скрипта выводится объект с динамическими данными через php, а затем использовать его в основном JS скрипте.